# Capture all Keyboard input when specific form is open

Tags: c#, windows, winforms, keyboard-events

I'm developing a software using C# and I need it tocapture the all keyboard input when a specific form is open.

I have a card reader that capture info as a Keyboard.
I will open a pop up to tell the user to pass the card and then I need to capture the input and check in my database if that is a valid card.

I couldn't find a way to capture the keyboard input when when a form is in focus.

Does anyone knows how to do it?

Comment: Hello and welcome to Stack Overflow!  When asking a question about a problem caused by your code, you will get much better answers if you provide code people can use to reproduce the problem.  Please see https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve to help you create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.

Comment: Just out of curiousity, how did you search for a way to capture keybord input that you didn't find any answers? Searching this site turns up a few...https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=capture+keyboard+input.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Form contains an Event called "KeyPress" that will work for what you are trying to do.  Click the little lightning bolt icon in properties to see your Events, double-click "KeyPress" to wire up the method.

If you are expecting more than one keypress (in other words, if you want a long string of numbers that represent the card number) you will need to store the input one character at a time like this:

```
// add a field to capture the input
string allInput = "";

private void Form1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
    allInput += e.KeyChar; // adds the last character pressed to the string
}
```

Note that if your focus is on something like a textbox, then the textbox will receive the KeyPress event and not the form.  You can add the same KeyPress event handler to every control in your form if there are only a few.  Otherwise, you are looking for something like a global keyhook, which is a lot more complicated.

Comment: Thanks a lot!! It worked! 
Sorry for the idiot question but I have never worked with C# before

Comment: Glad it helped!  If you find the code useful, an accepted answer would be appreciated.

Comment: I was trying to accept it but as I just created my account it seems I don't have enough reputation to rate it!

Comment: You would use the checkbox to accept, not the up-down arrows.  If you can't get it working, no worries.  I am happy to help either way!  Good luck.